# ERROR RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried everything on this. I know I am initiating the array with a 0, because I declare it right before the loop. Here is my code:

```dart
 final List<PrayerRequestEntity> prayerReturnList =
            <PrayerRequestEntity>[];

        int x = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < prayerRequestList.length; i++) {
          if (prayerRequestList[i].prayerRequestBoolAnswered == 1 &&
              boolAnswered == 1) {
            prayerReturnList[x] = prayerRequestList[i];
            x++;
          } else {
            //we want unanswered
            print('gumdum55: ${prayerRequestList[i].prayerRequestTitle}');
            print('gumdum56: here ${prayerReturnList[x].prayerRequestTitle}');
            prayerReturnList[x] = prayerRequestList[i];
            print('gumdum58: here');
            x++;
          }
        }
        emit(state.copyWith(status: PrayerRequestStatus.success));
        return prayerRequestList;
```

The output from the above is:

```
flutter: gumdum55: First Prayer Title
flutter: GUMDUM67: ERROR RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

I have wittled it own to the prayerReturnList[x] is the issue. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: calling prayerReturnList[x] and the list is empty will throw this rangeError

Comment: what you're trying to do with this line prayerReturnList[x] = prayerRequestList[i];

Comment: I am taking the specific entity at the point of prayerrequestlist[i] and copying it into prayerreturnlist[x]

Comment: replace it with this prayerReturnList.add(prayerRequestList[i])

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    final List<PrayerRequestEntity> prayerReturnList = <PrayerRequestEntity>[];

    for (PrayerRequestEntity prayerRequest in prayerRequestList) {
      if (prayerRequest.prayerRequestBoolAnswered == 1 && boolAnswered == 1) {
        prayerReturnList.add(prayerRequest);
      }else{
         prayerReturnList.add(prayerRequest);    
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! I'd mark this as answer correct, but I don't have enough points on here to do so.